# Generated unique id with 6 characters - handling when too much ids already used

Tags: database, probability, uniqueidentifier

​In my program you can book an item. This item has an id with 6 characters from 32 possible characters.

So my possibilities are 32^6. Every id must be unique.

```
func tryToAddItem {
 if !db.contains(generateId()) {
   addItem()
 } else {
   tryToAddItem()
 }
}
```

For example 90% of my ids are used. So the probability that I call tryToAddItem 5 times is `0,9^5 * 100 = 59%` isn't it?

So that is quite high. This are 5 database queries on a lot of datas.

When the probability is so high I want to implement a prefix „A-xxxxxx“.
What is a good condition for that?  At which time do I will need a prefix?

In my example 90% ids were use. What is about the rest? Do I threw it away?
What is about database performance when I call tryToAddItem 5 times? I could imagine that this is not best practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for response. I searched for alternatives and want show three possibilities.

**First possibility**: Create an `UpcomingItemIdTable` with 200 (more or less) valid `itemIds`. A task in the background can calculate them every minute (or what you need). So the action `tryToAddItem` will always get a valid `itemId`.

**Second possibility**

> Is remapping all ids to a larger space one time only a possibility?

In my case yes. I think for other problems the answer will be: it depends.

**Third possibility**: Try to generate an `itemId` and when there is a collision try it again.

Possible collisions handling: Do some test before. Measure the time to generate `itemIds` when there are already 1000,10.000,100.000,1.000.000 etc. entries in the table. When the `tryToAddItem` method needs more than 100ms (or what you prefer) then increase your length from 6 to 7,8,9 characters.

Some thoughts

- every request must be atomar
- create an index on `itemId`
- Disadvantages for long UUIDs in API: See https://zalando.github.io/restful-api-guidelines/#144

  > less usable, because...
  >   
  > -cannot be memorized and easily communicated by humans
  >   
  > -harder to use in debugging and logging analysis
  >   
  > -less convenient for consumer facing usage
  >   
  > -quite long: readable representation requires 36 characters and comes with higher memory and bandwidth consumption
  >   
  > -not ordered along their creation history and no indication of used id volume
  >   
  > -may be in conflict with additional backward compatibility support of legacy ids
  >   [...]

TLDR: For my case every possibility is working. As so often it depends on the problem. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 1):

> For example 90% of my ids are used. So the probability that I call tryToAddItem 5 times is 0,9^5 * 100 = 59% isn't it?

Not quite. Let's represent the number of call you make with the random variable `X`, and let's call the probability of an id collision `p`. You want the probability that you make the call *at most* five times, or in general at most `k` times:

```
P(X≤k) = P(X=1) + P(X=2) + ... + P(X=k)
= (1-p) + (1-p)*p + (1-p)*p^2 +... + (1-p)*p^(k-1)
= (1-p)*(1 + p + p^2 + .. + p^(k-1))
```

If we expand this out all but two terms cancel and we get:

```
= 1- p^k
```

Which we want to be greater than some probability, `x`:

```
1 - p^k > x
```

Or with `p` in terms of `k` and `x`:

```
p < (1-x)^(1/k)
```

where you can adjust `x` and `k` for your specific needs.

If you want less than a 50% probability of 5 or more calls, then no more than (1-0.5)^(1/5) ≈ 87% of your ids should be taken.

First of all make sure there is an index on the id columns you are looking up. Then I would recommend thinking more in terms of setting a very low probability of a very bad event occurring. For example maybe making 20 calls slows down the database for too long, so we'd like to set the probability of this occurring to <0.1%. Using the formula above we find that no more than 70% of ids should be taken.

But you should also consider alternative solutions. Is remapping all ids to a larger space one time only a possibility?

Or if adding ids with prefixes is not a big deal then you could generate longer ids with prefixes for all new items going forward and not have to worry about collisions.